# CurrentUser.LoginName returns too much information

Tags: 2013, user

Say I am logged in as domain\spuser this is what I am expecting in return when I access SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, but instead I am getting "i:0#.w|domain\spuser".

Anyone know why this is happening? Sure I can use string handling and get the chars right of the | char but I just think this is strange, I've never had to do it like that before.

Comment: This happens to me in our enviroment where we have both forms and active directory authentication enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Claims to Windows token, helping Sharepoint 2013 to identify the correct authentication provider

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535242.aspx

For getting / removing the Claims token:
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/

Also see this question I have answered before: [Why is SharePoint 2013 adding random characters in front of usernames in Web Application Policy users?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65981/why-is-sharepoint-2013-adding-random-characters-in-front-of-usernames-in-web-app/65992#65992)

Comment: Wonderful, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

try
            {
                if (SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.UseClaimsAuthentication == true)
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager mgr = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
                    if (mgr != null)
                    {
                        if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.Equals("SHAREPOINT\system", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            user= this.Page.User.Identity.Name;

```
                         if (user.Contains("|"))
                        {
                            user = user.Substring(user.IndexOf("|") + 1);
                        }
                        else if (user.Contains("\\"))
                        {
                            user = user.Substring(user.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        user = mgr.DecodeClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).Value;
                }
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```