# Granting User/Groups a Permission appends unreadable characters to the User/Group name

Tags: permissions

in SP2010 i created 3 Domain Groups, then Granted them permissions as View Only, everything is working fine, but the added group names has unreadable characters and a guid appended to end (see screenshot)[image]

what causes this ? or how can i remove the appended characters

Comment: The undreadable characters is the claims token, see here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65981/why-is-sharepoint-2013-adding-random-characters-in-front-of-usernames-in-web-app/65992#65992

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thank you for commenting, how would i remove these characters ?

Comment: Well that's the question! Seems something has gone wrong in the user profile sync. Have you performed a full sync?